# Specify time periods for multiple years

Tags: r

I have a data set with a variable "date", from 2001-01-01 to 2015-12-31. I need to generate a new variable to indicate different time periods.

Time interval: Jan 15 to Feb 10.

Jan 15 to Feb 10, 2015 -- Time = 1

Jan 15 to Feb 10, 2001-2014 -- Time = 0

Is there a good method to generate the new variable?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could use `mutate` with an `ifelse` statement.  If you provide some sample code it would be easier to illustrate how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If your date variable is not already a date time object, you can convert it using the `as.Date()` function like this:

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

The you can use an `ifelse` statement to create a new variable like this:

```
df$Time <- ifelse(df$Date > "2015-01-15" & df$Date < "2015-02-10", 1, 
ifelse((df$Date > "2014-01-15" & df$Date < "2014-02-10") | 
(df$Date > "2013-01-15" & df$Date < "2013-02-10") | 
(df$Date > "2012-01-15" & df$Date < "2012-02-10") | 
(df$Date > "2011-01-15" & df$Date < "2011-02-10"), 0, "NA"))
```

Comment: Thanks! It is correct for Time=1 (Jan 15 to Feb 10, 2015); however, for Time=0, it will include all time outside the period of Jan 15 to Feb 10, 2015. What I need for Time=0 is: Jan 15 to Feb 10, 2001, 2002, 2003 ...2014.

Comment: So what do you want for time periods outside of those? say for ex: Feb 11 2001

Comment: It will be  "na" for Feb 11, 2001 and other dates, I don't need these dates.

Comment: That is a very specific requirement. See my edited answer above and add the remainder of the years in a similar fashion

Comment: Thanks! it works. The problem is there are 14 years, we have to repeat 14 times. Perhaps there is a convenient approach to solve the problem?